# ¿Cómo volver a ejecutar un programa Python automáticamente?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que un programa en Python se ejecute solo de nuevo? Por ejemplo, hice un programa que es como una calculadora, luego de escribir los dos numeros a calcular, y que dé el resultado, el programa se termina. Mi pregunta es; ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el programa siga funcionando, sin tener que volver a ejecutarlo manualmente?. (El programa es más largo pero me decía que la publicación era mayormente código)

````
print("===========")
print("Calculadora")
print("===========")

print("Menú de opciones: \n")
print("Presiona 1 para suma \n")
print("Presiona 2 para resta \n")
print("Presiona 3 para multiplicación \n")
print("Presiona 4 para división \n")

opcion = int(input("¿Cuál es tu opción deseada?: "))

if opcion == 1:
    print("\n Vas a realizar una suma \n")

    primer_nro_suma = float(input("Ingresa el número a sumar: "))

    segundo_nro_suma = float(input("Ingresa el segundo número a sumar: "))

    resultado_suma = (primer_nro_suma + segundo_nro_suma)

    print("El resultado es: ", resultado_suma)

    print("Fin.")

elif opcion == 2:
    print("\n Vás a realizar una resta \n")

    primer_nro_resta = float(input("Ingresa el número a restar: "))

    segundo_nro_resta = float(input("Ingresa el segundo número a restar: "))
    
    resultado_resta = (primer_nro_resta - segundo_nro_resta)

    print("El resultado es: ", resultado_resta)
    
    print("Fin")

else:
    print("No existe esa opción, intenta de nuevo.") ```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si, debes envolver tu código en un bucle infinito, preferiblemente dando al usuario un opción para salir de él.

```py
print("===========")
print("Calculadora")
print("===========")

ejecutar = True

while ejecutar:

    # Ponemos todo dentro de un bucle, que por default,
    # se ejecutará infinitas veces.

    print("Menú de opciones: \n")
    print("Presiona 1 para suma \n")
    print("Presiona 2 para resta \n")
    print("Presiona 3 para multiplicación \n")
    print("Presiona 4 para división \n")

    opcion = int(input("¿Cuál es tu opción deseada?: "))

    if opcion == 1:
        print("\n Vas a realizar una suma \n")

        primer_nro_suma = float(input("Ingresa el número a sumar: "))

        segundo_nro_suma = float(input("Ingresa el segundo número a sumar: "))

        resultado_suma = (primer_nro_suma + segundo_nro_suma)

        print("El resultado es: ", resultado_suma)

        print("Fin.")

    elif opcion == 2:
        print("\n Vás a realizar una resta \n")

        primer_nro_resta = float(input("Ingresa el número a restar: "))

        segundo_nro_resta = float(input("Ingresa el segundo número a restar: "))
        resultado_resta = (primer_nro_resta - segundo_nro_resta)

        print("El resultado es: ", resultado_resta)


    # Una vez se ha realizado la operación, preguntamos
    # al usuario si desea realizar otra operación

    volver_a_ejecutar = input("¿Desea realizar otra operación? [s/n]: ")

    if volver_a_ejecutar == 'n':
        # Si el usuario ha decidido que ya no quiere 
        # realizar otra operación, cambiamos la variable
        # para que en la siguiente iteración ya no se
        # ejecute el contenido del ciclo while

        ejecutar = False

    else:
        print("No existe esa opción, intenta de nuevo.")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la respuesta, me ayduó muchísimo y aprendí algo nuevo que sin duda voy a implementar en mis próximos programas.!

Comment: Por nada, me da gusto que hayas aprendido algo nuevo.